# Xcode - Hiding .xcodeproj on files on GitHub repo via .gitignore

Tags: xcode, git, github, gitignore, xcode10

I am using Xcode to as my IDE for coding questions that I publish and commit to my GitHub account. However, I don't want the ProjectName.xcodeproj to be shown in the repo. Is this possible?
Also, how do you suggest managing .gitignore files in Xcode? The only solution I have come across is managing it manually via terminal.

I've tried creating a .gitignore file via gitignore.io and then going into the project directory via terminal and using curl http://gitignore.io/api/c++,xcode  > .gitignore. This has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This has no effect whatsoever.

This would have no effect if the files listed by the .gitignored are already tracked.

Try (now that you have a `.gitignore` in place) `git rm --cached -- ProjectName.xcodeproj`, and then see if that file is still in XCode Git status.
Commit and push: that file won't be in the repository anymore.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was looking for.